# Chrony sets system time but does not sync RTC

Tags: linux-kernel, hwclock, chrony

I have configured Chrony with rtcsync flag, which SHOULD "Enable kernel synchronization of the hardware real-time clock (RTC)", but that is not the case.

Chrony sets the system time correctly with ntp, but the RTC is untouched, and i can't seem to find out why that is. My guess is that the kernel doesn't recognize Chrony's request to sync the RTC, but that is just a guess.

**Versions**
Kernel: 4.19
Chrony: 3.5

***UPDATE:***

It appears that the external RTC is registered *after* the kernel tries to access it and this prevents syncing the RTC with the NTP synced system time.
from `dmesg`:

```
...
[    6.317060] hctosys: unable to open rtc device (rtc)
...
[   14.303503] rtc-ds1307 9-0068: registered as rtc0
...
```

I've done a temporary workaround by adding a cronjob that updates the hwclock every 10 minutes.

Comment: Following your update, you probably want to backport commit f9b2a4d6a5f1 ("rtc: class: support hctosys from modular RTC drivers") or compile the ds1307 driver statically in the kernel

Answer (score 0):

To get `rtcsync` working, you have to set the `RTC_SYSTOHC` and `RTC_SYSTOHC_DEVICE` kernel option properly as this simply asks the kernel to sync the system time to the RTC. It does so approximately every 11 minutes.

However, a better way of doing that is to use `rtcfile` (and `rtcdevice`) in that case, chrony will handle the RTC. It will even compute the RTC drift that could then be corrected if the RTC supports a trimming mechanism.

Comment: I've added these lines to ´/etc/chrony.conf´: ´rtcfile /etc/rtc´ and ´rtcdevice /dev/rtc0´, but it still only updates the system time and not the RTC. Do i need something more? The logs show nothing else than it's adjusting system clock

Comment: I've also tried to set the options you've mentioned. `RTC_SYSTOHC=y` and `RTC_SYSTOHC_DEVICE="rtc0"` but it still doesn't seem to update the hwclock